# Custom Styling in Exported Excel file

Tags: xml, datatables

I am trying to exported excel file from Datatable with custom style. I want to make first row background color blue with font color white. The code below makes background color blue but font color white is not getting applied.

```
function(xlsx) {
                                             
  var styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml'];
  
  f1 = '<font><sz val=\"12\" /><name val=\"Calibri\"/><color rgb=\"ffffff\"/></font>';
  s1 = '<fill><patternFill patternType=\"solid\"><fgColor rgb=\"213e82\" /></patternFill></fill>';
  s2 = '<xf numFmtId=\"168\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"6\" borderId=\"1\" applyFont=\"1\" applyFill=\"1\" applyBorder=\"1\" xfId=\"0\" applyAlignment=\"1\"><alignment horizontal=\"center\"/></xf>';

  styles.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML += f1;
  styles.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].innerHTML += s1 + f1;
  styles.childNodes[0].childNodes[5].innerHTML += s2;

             var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
             
             // first row
             $('row:eq(0) c', sheet).attr( 's', 67);

            //row with totals
            $('row:eq(-1) c', sheet).attr( 's', '2' );  //bold
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<xf>` tag definition, in the variable `s2`, change the font ID index from 0 to 1: `fontId="1"`.

Then it will refer to your newly added font from `f1`. This assumes you end up with 2 fonts in the style sheet, of course. You may need to adjust the index, if there are more.

**Update - Borders:**

Here is an example border entry in the style sheet, in the `<borders>` section:

```
<border diagonalUp="false" diagonalDown="false">
    <left style="thin">
        <color auto="1"/>
    </left>
    <right style="thin">
        <color auto="1"/>
    </right>
    <top style="thin">
        <color auto="1"/>
    </top>
    <bottom style="thin">
        <color auto="1"/>
    </bottom>
    <diagonal/>
</border>
```

**Update 2 - Controlling Exported Rows and Cols**

You can use the `exportOptions` feature to handle exporting only the 2nd data row onwards, and the 2nd column onwards:

```
    exportOptions: {
        rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            if (idx > 0) {
              return data;
            }
        },
        columns: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            if (idx > 0) {
              return data;
            }
          }
    },

    customize: function ( xlsx ) { ...},
```

This needs to be nested at the same level as your existing `customize` section. It uses a function to check the index of each row and column.

There is actually another shorter way to do this, where you explicitly list the row indexes and column indexes you need:

```
exportOptions: {
  rows: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
  columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
}
```

But since you want "everything to the end", the function is better.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I spent so many hours figuring it out, later this solution made me crazy, it was so stupid mistake I made. Can you help me in applying border on each cell?

Comment: No problem - we have all been there (and will be again). Borders are similar entries to fonts. I will add an example to my answer - should be sufficient to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Got it - $('row c', sheet).attr('s', '25');    Last desire I have - Is it possible to copy data from cell B2 instead of A1?

Comment: _copy data from cell B2_ - not sure what you mean. Do you mean export data from the HTML table, but ignoring the first data row and the first data column?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my previous comment. Yes this is what I meant "export data from the HTML table, but ignoring the first data row and the first data column"

Comment: Yes, possible - I'll have to remind myself - been a while. Will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. Would be a great help!